# Why is my simulator so large?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

For some reason my iPhone simulator is huge, so big I have to scroll to see the whole thing. How do I fix it to be a realistic size?

[image]

Comment: click in simulator window, then select window->scale->50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a different Scale from the Window menu of the Simulator app.